# Checking Textbox Text for Null

Tags: c#, null

I am using the following code to check for a null text-box, and, if it is null, skip the copy to clipboard and move on to the rest of the code.

I don't understand why I am getting a "Value cannot be NULL" exception.  Shouldn't it see the null and move on without copying to the clipboard?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox_Results.Text != null) Clipboard.SetText(textBox_Results.Text);            

    //rest of the code goes here;
}
```

Comment: What platform... Wpf? WinForms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably be doing your check like this:

```
if (textBox_Results != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_Results.Text))
```

Just an extra check so if `textBox_Results` is ever `null` you don't get a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: It should never be null.  Unless your adding the text box dynamically or trying to access while the form is being disposed (highly unlikely) you should be fine.  Note you should never try to access the UI control never from another form.  You should do it via a method.

Comment: Using  `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` makes the independent `!= null` check redundant. It's literally in the method name that it checks for null values.

Comment: @TylerH !string.IsNullOrWhitespace is being past textbox_Results.Text not textBox_Results. If textbox_Results is null and you access .Text it will throw a null reference exception before it gets the text value to pass into string.IsNullOrWhitespace.

That being said with newer version of C# I could do textBox_Results?.Text and remove the first check.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [String.IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx), if using .NET 4 [String.IsNullOrWhitespace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) to check .Text for Null values.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_Results.Text) Clipboard.SetText(textBox_Results.Text);            

        //rest of the code goes here;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just check if the Text is an empty string:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox_Results.Text != "") Clipboard.SetText(textBox_Results.Text);            

    //rest of the code goes here;
}
```

You can also check using the string.IsNullOrEmpty() method.